# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in mscorlib.dll - Debugging with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2015

Running my application in Visual Studio 2013 everything seems to work fine. (no exceptions, clean output window, etc.)

Running and debugging in Visual Studio 2015, I get infinite `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` fired at mscorlib.dll.

This is the code part I´m struggling with:

```
private async void ProvideBitmapImageToConsumer()
{
    using (var rAStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        while (_isPreviewing)
        {
            try
            {
                await _capture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateBmp(), rAStream);
                var currentImage = Image.FromStream(rAStream.AsStream());
                CurrentImage = new Bitmap(currentImage);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //We just toggled the cameras - try it again.
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my WPF application this part is about capturing a webcam stream using the `MediaCapture` class (WindowsRT) and converting it into a bitmap image for a QR-Decoder.

Does anyone have an Idea how to grab bitmaps out of the stream wihout exceptions in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: I believe they're just internal exceptions. If you put a breakpoint on the 'return' statement of your 'catch' block, is it triggered? If not, make sure that "Enable Just my Code" is checked in the debugging options of Visual Studio, and the exceptions should go away

Comment: That's how you coded it.  When you write catch-em-all exception handling code then you can't see why code throws an exception.

Comment: KooKiz was right, my three lines of stream converting code causes this internal mscorelib errors. Does anyone have an idea, how I could do it without these errors?